# Why are my records not being inserted in the same order they are being executed?

Tags: ms-access, vba, records

I'm using Microsoft Office Access as my DBMS and I'm using VBA to write my code for this project.

I'm doing data scraping for items on a website and I encountered something that appeared odd to me after I had inserted my data into a table.

In my code I use a loop to iterate through and collect all the items that the website has to offer.  Once I have all the data for one item I insert it into my table and then move on to the next.  There's 14,724 items that I need to insert into my table.  If I iterate over all of them, they will be added to the table but they are out of order once I look at them in the table, even though all the items are there, however if I adjust the loop to only collect...let's say only the first 10 items then they will appear in the same order in which they were collected which is the same order they appear in the source code for the website.

It is important to note that my table does not have an id field because it is not required as there's one other field that serves as a unique identifier for an item in the table.

This does not seem like a big issue but I'm curious as to why this happens.  Is there some kind of limitation when using MS-Access as your DBMS?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the records in the same order they were originally inserted, include a field which stores their insert order.

Comment: ^ Like a AutoNumber column, that you can later sort by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table is not a spreadsheet.

This is by design of any relational database engine. Records in a table have no order other than what you eventually assign or apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the data (ascending or descending) use a Query.  The Table doesn't have any order.  Even the Fields don't have any relevant order.